# android Html image getter want to be in straight order

Tags: android, html, image, getter

in my android layout i have some text and image, buttons etc placed with a scroll view . In the bottom of the page i want to show a text and image as shown below[image]

The image at the left side is of the correct order.(ie my design) where the text must be next to the image and if the text moves to the second line then also it needs to be away from the image. But for me it looks wrongly as shown in the the right side image.

Following is my code used for this,

```
CharSequence p = Html.fromHtml("<img src=\"board\" />"
                    + rawData[i]  + "<br>", this, null);
```

i used to have multiple data which i run in for loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < featureData.length; i++) 
   {
    CharSequence p = Html.fromHtml("<img src=\"bone\"/>"+" "+ featureData[i] + "<br>", featuregetter, null);
    event_feature_img.append(p);
   }
```

and next comes the following

```
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Log.i(" get drawable mathod ", "");
        Bitmap B = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.categories);
        BitmapDrawable BD = new BitmapDrawable(B);
        BD.setBounds(10, 10, B.getWidth(), B.getHeight());

        return BD;
    }
```

How can i get the above said one...

Comment: Try `CharSequence p = Html.fromHtml("<img src=\"bone\"  style=\"float: left;\" />"+"<div  style=\"float: left;\">"+ featureData[i] + "</div><br>", featuregetter, null);`

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib  - by using ur code the image is in one line and the text starts below the image, i want the text as shown in the above image(left side) in my question - thanx

Answer (score 2):

use xml or create control dynamically as @amc said.

### XML like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="2" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yourtext" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rightlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yourtext" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

### or through programetically :

```
LinearLayout leftLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    leftLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    int size = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<size; i++){
      LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);       
      TextView tv = new TextView(this);
      ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
      tv.setText("your text");
      iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
      ll.addView(iv);
      ll.addView(tv);
      leftLayout.addView(ll);
    }
```

same way for rightLayout and add these(leftLayout and rightLayout ) in your mainLayout having orientation horizontal.

Hope helpful to you.

Comment: the programmatical method is right, but my layout consists of lot of images and buttons, tabbar and a swipe method. but i need an answer - as i have asked in my ques...

Comment: can you please post screen shot or screen structure?

Answer (score 0):

First I would really recommend using xml layouts for this type of thing. Its a lot easier to lay things out there then in code.

Either way, this is basically what you want for each line:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/img_file_name"
    />
    <TextView
        android:text="This is text"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

There is more boilerplate you need in the xml, but you can find that stuff pretty easily in the android docs.

You can also accomplish this in code, but its not recommended. It would be something like this within an activity:

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);
ImageView image = new ImageView();
image.setImageBitmap(yourBitmap);
parent.addView(image);
TextView text = new TextView();
text.setText("your text");
parent.addView(text);
```

In both cases, the text will wrap, but stay within its own box and not go under the image.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this [sample app](http://j.mp/votedroid101) from the 2011 Google I/O Android Bootcamp session.  It implements a ListView with a list adapter that shows an interface very much like your screen shot.  (You will need to go into `ChooseAndroidActivity.java` and change `ArrayAdapter<String>(...)` to `AndroidListAdapter_lab(this)` to see the compound list entries.)